# Make a request scoped bean singleton when request-scope is not available

Tags: java, spring, scope

I have the following code to define a bean request scoped bean inside my Spring application.

```
@Bean       
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public MyBean myBean() {
    return new MyBean(); // actually it is a more complex initialization
}
```

But sometimes I will want to use the same bean in a offline application where `request` scope is not available, only `singleton` and `prototype` are.

Is there a way to make this same bean assume a `singleton` form when `request` is not available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you rely on a spring profile ? 
You could maybe extract the bean creation in a private method used by 2 `@Bean` with different `@Scope` and `@Profile`

Something like this :

```
@Bean     
@Profile('prod')    
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public MyBean myBeanProd() {
    return getMyBean()
}

@Bean   
@Profile('test')    
@Scope(value = "singleton", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public MyBean myBeanWithoutRequestScope() {
    return getMyBean()
}

privateMyBean getMyBean() {
    return new MyBean(); // actually it is a more complex initialization
}
```

Comment: It works very well. I had neved used `@Profile` before.